# Jenkins (Pipeline) Boolean Parameter in Powershell confusing

Tags: powershell, jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline, boolean

I have a parametrized Jenkins Pipeline Script, where I pass a Boolean Parameter "isModuleUpdate".

When I use this parameter in my Pipeline Script I get confusing results.
My Script:

```
 Write-Host ">>> isModuleUpdate as String: $Env:isModuleUpdate"
 Write-Host ">>> isModuleUpdate as Variable: " $Env:isModuleUpdate
 if ($Env:isModuleUpdate) {
      Write-Host ">>> ModuleUpdate is checked!"
 }
```

When I run my Script, the Result is:

```
>>> isModuleUpdate as String: false
>>> isModuleUpdate as Variable: false
>>> ModuleUpdate is checked!
```

What is the sexiest way to check this variable corectly?

Comment: You can also use `if([bool]::Parse($Env:isModuleUpdate)) { # here is for $true }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recall having issues with checking booleans in PowerShell as well. Ultimately, `-eq $true` worked:

```
 if ($Env:isModuleUpdate -eq $true) {
```

Answer (score 3):

From [about_Environment_Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2):

> Environment variables, unlike other types of variables in PowerShell, are always stored as a string and can't be empty.

Your `if` statement evaluates to `true`, because your string variable is not empty. In other words, it contains the string `false` and not a boolean value. Do a proper string comparison instead:

```
if ($Env:isModuleUpdate -like 'true') {...
```